# Sending email reminder automatically with Outlook 2016

Tags: office-365, calendar, outlook

I recently purchased Office 365, and it came with Outlook 2016. I used to use Outlook on the internet to set up recurring appointments. Reminder emails would be sent to the attendees a day before the appointment. It would do this for every occurrence.

I've been trying to figure out how to do that with Outlook 2016, but with no luck. I tried using the information from this link [superuser.com/scheduled-and-recurring-email-in-outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/635094/scheduled-and-recurring-email-in-outlook), but it only sent an email for the first occurrence. It didn't send another one the next day.

How can I set up a reminder that gets sent to a certain email address every time it occurs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about installable software.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this w/ OL 2016 as-is. There are add-ins and various kludge versions of VBA script which will provide this, but the stock product doesn't. This is because Outlook is a Naughties (i.e. 2000's) piece of software that Microsoft forgot about in the 1990's, no matter that Google calendar (and even Outlook.com at one time) have this as a standard feature.